# TFS: Managing assembly version number?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

any good approach for managing assembly version numbers in TFS, possibly together with using the same number for the build number?

I would be most interested in an approach that:

- Maintains the first three elements of the version
- Counts the rest upward for every "official" build (i.e. a build originating from certain templates only - no need to count up for something like a gated checkin, but the following regular integration build SHOULD count up.
- Labels the builds, so that a manual "release" build can be triggered.

Any solution? How are other people handling this? Right now the (new) TFS is happily building with the same assembly version all around ;)

Something coding the complete assembly version with date etc. is not acceptable - I want that number to "follow rules", and having the date in there is not one of them ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Workflow-Activity-for-TFS-Build-2010.aspx#tb) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510134032/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx)) on how to create custom TFS workflow activities might be useful, as the example activity he creates does something similar to what you're after.